# JSON response throws as undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json

I' am running into some issues from yesterday. Below are all the details that am currently working with.

**PHP**

```
$json = array(
   'total_cost' => '109.38',
    'insurance' => 1
);
echo json_encode( $json );
```

**Console**

```
{"total_cost":109.38,"insurance":"1"}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post(ajax_url, {'action':action, 'nonce':nonce, 'insurance':insurance}, function( data ){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert( data.total_cost );
});
```

The above throws '*undefined*'. Any idea what am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: your code seems to work from here, please post more code as there may be an error elsewhere, and try to use the full function of jquery "ajax"

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Blaztix how would using `$.ajax` make any difference?

Comment: @RobM I see `{"total_cost":109.38,"insurance":"1"}`

Comment: Is that before or after `JSON.parse`? Wondering if your result is already an object (not a string), have you tried this without the `JSON.parse` step?

Comment: @RobM Yes I tried and it also shows `"{\"total_cost\":109.38,\"insurance\":\"1\"}"`

Comment: Well `console.log(JSON.parse("{\"total_cost\":109.38,\"insurance\":\"1\"}").total_cost)` works just fine - what do you mean it "throws" undefined? Are you getting an error or does the `alert` say "undefined"?

Comment: @RobM Yes the alert shows `undefined`. I' am going rewrite the code. That will fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Add 'json'` as the last argument to `$.post`. Then jQuery will parse the response automatically, and you shouldn't call `JSON.parse()` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem could be when you use json.parse(data) I leave you a example this works correctly

$.post(url_lista_precios_prod,{id_prod:id_producto}, function(data){

```
   var ar=data[0]; },'json');
```

test well